# PHP Fatal error: Access level to FrontLocalBusiness::__construct() must be public (as in class LocalBusiness) while execute wp-cli command

Tags: php, singleton, wp-cli

I have created a parent class (LocalBusiness) and two child classes FrontLocalBusiness and AdminLocalBusiness to inheritance same properties and getter/setter from parent class and reduce amount of code.

But i'm getting this error because FrontLocalClass is a singleton.

**PHP Fatal error:  Access level to FrontLocalBusiness::__construct() must be public (as in class LocalBusiness) in /home/lorraine/www/wp-content/themes/lorraine/components/front/local-business/local-business.php on line 6**

So... Can I share code from parent class to child class without change singleton pattern from FrontLocalBusiness...

LocalBusiness
[image]

FrontLocalBusiness
[image]

**EDIT**: I have updated php to v8.0.11

The problem occur when I execute a wp-cli command from command line. I'm not getting this error in development and wordpress doesnt launch any error.

Only occur when I execute:

wp option update whl_page login --ssh=user@domain.com --path=/home/domain/www/

Thanks

Comment: Which PHP version are you running? [This was classified as a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61970) and fixed in PHP 7.2. See https://3v4l.org/gcSK5. If you're running anything earlier than that then you'll need to change the visibility of the constructor(s). Does the parent class need a public constructor? Or could you mark them both as protected?

Comment: I had PHP 7.2.34. Now I have updated to PHP 8.0.11 but the error persist

Comment: From your edit, it sounds like you're not running PHP 7.2+ on the command line. If you are, then we need a minimal, reproducible example. Having a private constructor in a child class shouldn't raise that error in any version newer than that.

Comment: If I run pw --info I can see this:
OS: Linux 5.4.0-89-generic #100~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 29 10:59:42 UTC 2021 x86_64
Shell: /bin/bash
PHP binary: /usr/bin/php8.0
PHP version: 8.0.10.

In local I have 8.0.10 and by the way, I have updated the php version on the server which is 8.0.11

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a child class method more restrictive that it's parent class method for PHP version below `7.2`. In your case you should make both constructors protected/public to make it work. Look at the code below.

```
class Dad {
    protected function __construct()
    {
        echo "Dad";
    }
}

class Child extends Dad
{
    private static $instance = null;

    protected function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
}

$child = Child::getInstance();
```